# xmlbean : dealing with int and a missing element

Tags: java, xmlbeans

When binding a POJO with xmlbean, if a tag, normally with an int, is missing, it is mapped with 0.
I know that adbean would map it with Integer.MIN_VALUE. Is there a such possibility or anything else with xmlbean ?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, change the WSDl : put an Integer, not int

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand the question, but you can use `.isSetFoo()` to check if the foo element is present in the xml document.